# SEO optimization multiple domains and multilingual site

Tags: seo, multilingual, multiple-domains

I am taking SEO of our website to another level. I read a lot about it and study all aspects of how to properly handle multiple domains and languages. For now we use three domain names `www.myurl.eu`, `www.myurl.de` and `www.myotherurl.com`.

All sites were pointed to the same content and I soon learned out that having multiple domains is not a good practice (good reading regarding this: http://www.seo.com/blog/multiple-domains-seo/). OK I solved this as suggested by SEO and Google experts, to pick one primary domain and do a `301 permanent redirect` from other domains! OK solved!

BUT! Then I attended on an technical SEO brief in UK, where a SEO guy was speaking  something about local search and how UK Google search will prefer `.co.uk domains`. And it turns out he was correct. Also the link I have posted above there is also a paragraph regarding this:

> Country Specific Domains
>
> This is less of a tactic, and more of a “must do,” and is therefore my
>   exception to multiple domains. It’s an exception because all of the
>   problems above do not apply when you get into other countries. In
>   fact, in order to have the best results in international SEO, you’ll
>   need to have a country specific TLD (or top level domain). For
>   example, if you’re doing business in England, you will have a hard
>   time ranking without a .co.uk domain. You can still rank without a
>   country level TLD, but it’s an uphill battle. And by uphill, I mean
>   Rocky Mountains-type uphill.

Q1:
So OK, to rank high for my business in UK I will need a `www.myurl.co.uk`. I have bought one. Now question that arises from this. Is a `www.myurl.co.uk` again a 301 redirect to my primary domain or not? How should I handle this?

Q2:
Then there is a multilingual aspect of all this. My site is build in a way so Language sites are altered with an /lang/ code in url. Example:

- `www.myurl.eu/en/products` -> english products site
- `www.myurl.eu/de/products` -> same site in german
- `www.myotherurl.com/en/products` -> 301 redirect to
  `www.myurl.eu/en/products`

So now what to do with my country specific domains `www.myurl.co.uk` and `www.myurl.de`? Should these be 301 redirects to main domains like `www.myurl.co.uk` -> `www.myurl.eu/en/` and `www.myurl.de` -> `www.myurl.eu/de/`? Is this the right way to go with?

Q3: should I really go this way having separate country level domains in countries where I do business? I haven't seen let's say Apple having an `apple.co.uk` and so on? How important is this really?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [webmasters.se], but read [their on-topic page](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. Stack Overflow isn't for asking "How do I have [*some effect*] on how a 3rd party site interprets my site?" Once you've know *exactly* what you want to do (not the 2nd/3rd order *effect* you want) Stack Overflow *may* (read the [on-topic page](/help/on-topic)) be able to help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Q1.** In my opinion you should use 301 end redirect it to
  www.myurl.eu/en.
- **Q2.** Yes, you should point country specific domain    into that
  country language version of your site. eg. www.myurl.co.uk    should
  be redirected to www.myurl.eu/en
- **Q3.** Country domain is only one of dozens of things which makes
  certain page to be connected with    that    or another
  country/region. I think you shouldn't take so much    care    about
  that. There are much more important things connected with       pages
  internationalization than country domain, eg. links from
  country-local pages, diversity of that links, content value, etc.

Comment: Thx Marcin! What do you mean by `There are much more important things connected with pages internationalization than country domain, eg. links from country-local pages, diversity of that links, content value, etc.` ?

Comment: It is much more important to have links from pages from country you are trying to position in than to have a country domain from there.

Comment: If I understand you right it's more important! to have back-links from other country sites pointed to my country site? For example `www.someuksite.co.uk` to link to my UK site...? Should this link  point to my main domain `www.myurl.eu/uk/products` or to `www.myurl.co.uk/products` which will then do a 301 redirect to `www.myurl.eu/uk/products`?

Comment: There is a bit of PR loss through every 301 redirect so I think www.myurl.eu/uk/products would be better. But on the other hand users could remember myurl.co.uk easier (as co.uk is their default domain), so both have pros and cons. I would advice mixing that two destination links :)

Comment: Thanks I will take your comments into note. But then again here http://www.seoptimise.com/blog/2011/09/international-seo-strategy-domains-subdomains-or-subfolders.html states: `1) When to use local TLDs (top-level domains)?` In my opinion, having a local TLD is `still the number one way` of showing Google that a website is intended for a specific geographical target. And I can’t see that changing either, despite huge improvements in Google Webmaster Tools over geo-targeting settings."